# Django order by queryset by requests values (id__in)

Tags: django

I query a Django table by a list of IDs

```
hclistofcases = testcase.objects.filter(id__in="[182, 180, 184, 179, 178, 181, 183"))
```

That words an returns a queryset, however the queryset is not in the list order (i.e. record 182 first and 183 last).  Is there a way to ensure that the quesryset is returned in the list order?  I am currently using sqlite as the database

Any hep would be appreciated

Thanks

Grant

Comment: You can maybe use something like this : .order_by('id_in')

Answer (score 1):

```
empty = testcase.objects.none()
_ = []
for i in [182, 180, 184, 179, 178, 181, 183]:
    _.append(testcase.fiter(id=i))
return empty.union(*_)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) you can append `.order_by(id)` to get ascending order.

Comment: Am I right though that that orders by id not the order of the inputted list, I don't want this 178,179,180,181,182,183,184 but rather 182,180,184, 179,178,181,183.

Comment: What's the selection criteria that is dictating the list order? You can use order_by on any field in your originating table. Alternatively you could do something like:

```
these_ids = [182, 180, 184, 179, 178, 181, 183]
hclistofcases = []
for item in these_ids:
    hclistofcases.append(testcase.objects.filter(id=item))
```

Python will enforce the list order, but this isn't very performant because the database will be making separate queries for every ID.

Comment: I ended up doing that.  Adding the values to a dictionary.  The number of items is only going to be less than 10, so I can live with any possible performance issue